# Search whole sentence

Tags: vba, ms-word

In the below example. when i try to select with it supposed to select the whole sentence itself not the partial. if its dont find the whole sentence, it should return false

```
With Selection.Find
.Text = "Hi How Are You"
.Replacement.Text = ""
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
a = Selection.Find.Execute
If a = True Then           
End If
```

Comment: In the above example when i try to search using "How". its return true, it should not be

Comment: What returns true?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to set the `MatchWholeWord` parameter to `True` to have the find operation locate only entire words, not text that is part of a larger word. Corresponds to the `Find` whole words only check box in the `Find and Replace` dialog box. Also you may need to set `MatchCase` to True to specify that the find text is case-sensitive. Corresponds to the Match case check box in the Find and Replace dialog box (Edit menu).